# Express this vector as a linear combinations by given vectors.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

Here are a parallelogram $PQRS$.

Let the internal dividing point of the $\overline{PQ}$ by $2:1$  is $A$, middle point of the $\overline{PS}$ is $B$ and intersection point between those is $C$

Express $\overrightarrow {PC} $as a linear combination of the $\overrightarrow {PQ}$ and $\overrightarrow {PS}$.
[image]

---

Here is my attempt

[image]

All I have to do find the ratio $\alpha$.

What should I do next? Thanks.

P.s.) Lately checking the answer sheet, it said $\alpha$ is ${1 \over 4}$

Comment: That cannot be right: $PQ$ and $RS$ are parallel so any linear combination will also be parallel to them, and $PC$ isn't.  Please **proof read your question carefully** and edit it.

Comment: Thanks for your point out. I  will edit it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\alpha$ can be obtained from the area ratios as follows,

$$\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha} =\frac{\triangle BAS}{\triangle RAS}=\frac{\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{3}
$$

where we observe that △BAS and △RAS share the same base AS. This allows their area ratio to be expressed as $\alpha/(1-\alpha)$, which is proportional to their heights. Furthermore, from the side partitions given, △RAS is $\frac{1}{2}$ of the area PQRS and, similarly, △BAS is $\frac{1}{6}$ of the area PQRS.

Thus,

$$\alpha=\frac{1}{4}$$

and $$\vec{PC}=\frac{1}{4}\vec{PQ}+\frac{5}{8}\vec{PS}$$

Comment: Why does $$\frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha} =\frac{△BAS}{△RAS}=\frac{\frac{2}{3} \cdot \frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}}=\frac{1}{3}
$$ holds?

Comment: Please see the added explanation in the answer.